# List adapter for AdMob NativeExpressAdView

Tags: android, admob

I would like to use the new native ads by AdMob and display them in a list, just like other networks are doing it. For this I need to have an adapter wrapper class that will handle all the native ad loading and list handling automatically. Is there any simple way of doing this? The [admobadapter](https://github.com/clockbyte/admobadapter) is a good example but it uses the content and install type of native ads that also use a user defined layout (unlike the NativeExpressAdView that does not need a layout).

Answer (score 0):

if you use RecyclerView, you need to:

1. Create two constants

   static final int TYPE_PUB = 0;
       static final int TYPE_CELL = 1;

2. Override the methode getItemViewType

```
     @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            if (isPositionHeader(position))
                return TYPE_PUB;
            return TYPE_CELL;
        }
```

3. Create 2 viewholders (one for admob and the seconde for you item list)
4. You onCreateViewHolder will look like this :

```
 @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (viewType == TYPE_PUB) {
            return new ViewHolderAdMob(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_admob, parent, false));
        } else {
            return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_card_small, parent, false));

        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The newest version now supports Native Express ads. More info on their [github](https://github.com/clockbyte/admobadapter/wiki/Cookbook#the-recipe-3-for-a-recyclerview-scrolling-with-express-ads)